# 10 watt wireless charging receiver for phone

Tags: smartphones, power-supply

I want to add wireless charging to my USB-C phone.

I have found many 5 watt Qi charging receivers online, like [these](https://www.banggood.com/buy/wireless-charging-receiver.html), but no faster ones.

5 watt is way too slow compared to my usual wired fast charging!

**Question:** Where can I buy a 10 watt (2 amp) USB-C wireless charging receiver for my phone?